# issue when i try to show image on php

Tags: php, html

i have only a small question on php also i want show an image on slider also i get error on data-thumb" " because the cod on it it's not good writen , can you check it please

```
 echo '<img data-thumb="<img src="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url .'" />"
 src="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url .'" 
 alt="'. $image->file_title .'"   >';
```

also i get this result :

```
<img data-thumb="<img src=" https:="" website.com="" images="" 
stories="" virtuemart="" product="" product-03.jpg"="">"                                               
src="https://www.website.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/product-03.jpg" 
  alt="VM Cart Logo "   /&gt;                                       </div>
```

how can i fix it please ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to put a full img tag inside a data attribute?  That seems ... odd

Comment: Agree.. `JURI::root().$image->file_url` seems to come with double-quotes, and a whole img tag in data-attributes containing other double-quotes *must* break your output.

Comment: thanks also there is only a small issue that it must be an img on the data-thumb to print like this result :

    <img data-thumb='<img src="https://sitecom.com/pic.png" />'  src="https://sitecom.com/pic.png" alt="photo by Barn Images">

how can i add my image source `src="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'" `  into the data-thumb  like here `data-thumb='<img src="https://sitecom.com/pic.png" />'`      ?

Answer (score 0):

Your output isn't producing valid HTML. Try this.

```
echo '<img 
   src="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'" 
   alt="'.$image->file_title.'"
   data-thumb="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'">';
```

**Update**

> thanks also there is only a small issue that it must be an img on the
>   data-thumb to print like this result : ' src="sitecom.com/pic.png" alt="photo by
>   Barn Images"> how can i add my image source
>   src="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'" into the data-thumb like here
>   data-thumb='[image]' ?

Can I ask why you want to embed an `<img>` tag in the `data-thumb` attribute? It can be done but usually, you'd just construct the `<img>` later when you actually use the contents of `data-thumb`. Anyhoo, I'll update my answer to match what you want.

This is valid HTML according to https://validator.w3.org/nu/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$url = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150';
$title = 'This is my image title';

echo '<img 
       src="' . $url . '" 
       alt="' . $title . '"
       data-thumb=\'<img src="' . $url . '">\'>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Using your variables, it would be.

```
$url = JURI::root().$image->file_url;
$title = $image->file_title;

echo '<img 
       src="' . $url . '" 
       alt="' . $title . '"
       data-thumb=\'<img src="' . $url . '">\'>';
```

Comment: thanks also there is only a small issue that it must be an img on the data-thumb to print like this result :

    <img data-thumb='<img src="https://sitecom.com/pic.png" />'  src="https://sitecom.com/pic.png" alt="photo by Barn Images">

how can i add my image source `src="'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'" `  into the data-thumb  like here `data-thumb='<img src="https://sitecom.com/pic.png" />'`      ?